# Rest Period between Exercises?

Tags: weightlifting, rest

So people (including me) obviously talk about resting in between two sets of the same exercise and how long they should be. Now I'm wondering, what about rest in between two exercises (in addition to the small rest you get from warmup-sets, switching plates or cleaning up after yourself).

For start, it's clear that you don't really need a rest period between let's say a bench press and a row, because they work completly different muscles. But what about exercise combinations like Squat + Lunge, Deadlift + Leg Curl or Pullup + Row?

**Is a rest period between two exercises that work similar muscles, like given in the above example, recommended?** If yes, how long should they be in relation to the between-set-rest period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their always need for rest period between common exercises, and it depends on your body type and your level of workout. For starter I always recommend max of 2 min rest after each exercise of same muscle. like you mention that doing whole workout of leg muscles you need to give them a little relapses time to recover, because over strain can cause injuries which leads to lot worst cases.
As it turns out, there’s primarily 3 major factors that influence what your ideal rest times should be:

What intensity/rep range you are using for a given exercise.
How demanding that exercise is on your body as a whole.
Your primary goal (building muscle, increasing strength, losing fat, etc.).
For maximal strength, rest periods must be long enough for the nervous system to recover for future high-intensity bouts. In most cases, rest periods of three to five minutes’ between heavy strength sets (85%+ 1-Rm) suffice.

Shorter rest periods impair physical performance during subsequent sets (Rahimi et al.) and, over several weeks, attenuate strength increases compared to long rest periods (Spiering et al.) Anything less than what’s needed leaves weight on the bar and limits maximal strength gains.
Hope this be helpful